# SpringBootTest with @EmbeddedKafka, @KafkaListener not invoked when using @MockBean

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I'm seeing an issue when using `@MockBean` whereby the class under test contains a `@KafkaListener` annotation and isn't invoked.

I've tried the following:

- `@SpyBean`
- A TestConfiguration class with the bean containing `@KafkaListener` with a mock
- Removing the base class which brings in a bunch of producer configs to publish to embedded broker

Something that did actually work was changing the dependency to var and replacing it in a `@BeforeEach` in the Test class

Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(
    initializers = [ITKafkaPropertiesContextInitializer::class]
)
@EmbeddedKafka(
    controlledShutdown = true,
    ports = [9093],
    topics = [
        "embedded-test-topic-1",
        "embedded-test-topic-2"
    ],
    partitions = 1,
    brokerProperties = [
        "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093"
    ]
)
class ConsumerITTest : AbstractKafkaTest() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, Message>


    @Value("\${spring.kafka.event-topic}")
    lateinit var kafkaTopic: String

    @MockBean
    lateinit var delegator: MessageDelegator

    @Test
    fun `should receive message and invoke delegator`() {
        val event = JsonReader.read("src/test/resources/messages/create.json", Message::class.java)

        eventKafkaTemplate.send(
            ProducerRecord(producerRecord)
        )

        await().atMost(Duration.FIVE_SECONDS).untilAsserted {
          ...
        }

    }

}
```

Without the `@MockBean` everything works as expected, with `@MockBean` I can't even reach the breakpoint because the `@KafkaListener` function is never called.

```
@Component
class Consumer(
    val delegator: Delegator
) {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["#{'\${spring.kafka.topic}'}"],
        groupId = "#{'\${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}'}",
        containerFactory = "eventContainerFactory"
    )
    fun onMessage(
        @Payload data: ConsumerRecord<String, Message>?,
        @Headers headers: Map<String?, ByteArray?>,
    ) {
      ... //Breakpoint here never reached when using @MockBean
```

Just to confirm, this all works totally fine until I use these annotations to replace with a bean in the context with a mock

Comment: Having the same issue with a service. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have same issue and also have no idea why can the mocked kafkaListener is not invoked, it might have something to do with the mock will not configure the kafkalistener with the correct topic, but my test work with the @Spybean, When I use @ SpyBean then my kafkaListener can be stubed and will be invoked.What error did you get when you use the @ SpyBean?

Comment: I have the same issue and I am pretty sure that it is a race condition. The embedded kafka is not completely up when the test is executed.
I opened up an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34595

Answer (score 0):

I opened up an issue on GitHub and got some alternatives on how to make it work (thanks to Gary Russell):

- Set `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest` (it defaults to latest) so the consumer will receive the already sent record when it subscrtibes.
- Add a rebalance listener and wait the partition assignment
- Call `ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment()`

Here is the original comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34595#issuecomment-1468144074

I set the property in my project and it worked fine.